# Seed Data with ICollection?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a school project with a one to many relationship (Contact can have many Addresses). But I don't know how to seed it correctly.

In my Data models Contact has a `virtual ICollection<Address> Addresses` and the address object has the foreign key of `ContactId`.

So here is my seed data (code first) And i need to make it so when i type in the contacts last name in a search bar it will pull up all the info on that contact (address Info).

So how do i associate the info together in my seed data so when you search it pulls up what it is supposed to?

```
    namespace Success.Data.Migrations
{
    public class Seeder
    {
        public static void Seed(SuccessContext context,
            bool seedContacts = true,
            bool seedAddresses = true)

        {
            if (seedContacts) SeedContacts(context);
            if (seedAddresses) SeedAddresses(context);
        }

        private static void SeedContacts(SuccessContext context)
        {
            context.Contacts.AddOrUpdate(l => l.LastName,
                new Contact() { FullName = "Darth Vader", FirstName = "Darth", LastName = "Vader", },
                new Contact() { FullName = "Luke Skywalker", FirstName = "Luke", LastName = "Skywalker", },
                new Contact() { FullName = "Tony Stark", FirstName = "Tony", LastName = "Stark", },
                new Contact() { FullName = "Ricky Bobby", FirstName = "Ricky", LastName = "Bobby", },
                new Contact() { FullName = "Trix Rabbit", FirstName = "Trix", LastName = "Rabbit", });

            context.SaveChanges();

        }

        private static void SeedAddresses(SuccessContext context)
        {
           context.Addresses.AddOrUpdate(h => h.HomeAddress,
               new Address() { HomeAddress = "1300 DeathStar", BusinessAddress = "444 Imperial Fleet", PoBox = "PO Box 1335", ContactId = 1, },
               new Address() { HomeAddress = "1997 Endor", BusinessAddress = "448 Rebel Fleet", PoBox = "PO Box 1339", ContactId = 2, },
               new Address() { HomeAddress = "1224 Malibu Point", BusinessAddress = "657 Stark Industries", PoBox = "PO Box 1337", ContactId = 3, },
               new Address() { HomeAddress = "9978 Fast LN.", BusinessAddress = "532 NASCAR Race Track", PoBox = "PO Box 1333", ContactId = 4, },
               new Address() { HomeAddress = "9864 Cerial Box LN", BusinessAddress = "8432 Kellog Dr.", PoBox = "PO Box 1338", ContactId = 5, });

           context.SaveChanges();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If it's a school project, isn't the *point* of it to figure things out for yourself?

Comment: yes. And I have tried several different things and have had to re do my whole assignment several times before i finally asked for help on this forum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have another method that seeds both the contacts and address. You will need an extra if/else switch

```
if (seedContacts && seedAddresses)
{
    SeedContactsAndAddress(context);
}
else
{
    if (seedContacts) SeedContacts(context);
    if (seedAddresses) SeedAddresses(context);
}
```

And the SeedContactsAndAddress Method would look like this:

```
private static void SeedContactsAndAddress(StoreContext context)
{
    // Each Address, which I believe is a collection in this case, but there is only
    // one, will have to be created and added to each contact.

    var addressesForDarthVader = new List<Address>
    {
        new Address { HomeAddress = "1300 DeathStar", BusinessAddress = "444 Imperial Fleet", PoBox = "PO Box 1335" }
        // Add more addresses for Darth Vader if you need to
    };

    // Rinse and repeat for the other contacts;

    context.Contacts.AddOrUpdate(l => l.LastName,
        new Contact() { FullName = "Darth Vader", FirstName = "Darth", LastName = "Vader", Addresses = addressesForDarthVader },
        new Contact() { FullName = "Luke Skywalker", FirstName = "Luke", LastName = "Skywalker", },
        new Contact() { FullName = "Tony Stark", FirstName = "Tony", LastName = "Stark", },
        new Contact() { FullName = "Ricky Bobby", FirstName = "Ricky", LastName = "Bobby", },
        new Contact() { FullName = "Trix Rabbit", FirstName = "Trix", LastName = "Rabbit", });

    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: thank you very appreciated, what you did makes sense...but I just added a ContactId to each of my addresses 1-5. I believe that would also work?

Comment: You would still need a separate method to do both the customers and addresses. And you would have to call Savechanges on the customers first and hope that the the generated contactId's would be in the correct order... I am guessing these are auto increment Id's? And assuming that the Addresses have a foreign key relationship to Contacts then you wouldn't be able to insert the addresses into the DB without the contactId being valid.